# Incorrect session results for phpinfo(INFO_MODULES)

Tags: php, session

In PHP 8.1.5 I set the session parameters with this:

```
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 800,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'samesite' => 'Strict',
]);
session_start([
    'lazy_write' => true,
    'use_strict_mode' => true,
    'sid_length' => 46,
    'sid_bits_per_character' => 6,
    'cache_limiter' => 'nocache',
]);
```

Yet when I output `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES)` I see this:

| Directive | Local Value | Master Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| session.cache_expire | 180 | 180 |
| session.cache_limiter | nocache | nocache |
| session.cookie_domain | no value | no value |
| session.cookie_path | / | / |
| session.cookie_samesite | no value | no value |
| session.cookie_secure | 0 | 0 |
| session.gc_divisor | 1000 | 1000 |
| session.gc_maxlifetime | 1440 | 1440 |
| session.gc_probability | 1 | 1 |
| session.lazy_write | On | On |
| session.sid_bits_per_character | 5 | 5 |
| session.sid_length | 26 | 26 |

(I've deleted some lines here)
Some values seem not reported by phpinfo but if I look at the session cookie I do see the values reflected. Yes, I destroy and recreated the session just to make sure.

```
PHPSESSID=JqUFyb9csa1xNFi7L,qXE71pph04nFaDAGyB,NVl8sDBT3; expires=Sat, 04-Jun-2022 10:17:17 GMT; Max-Age=800; path=/; domain=www.example.com; SameSite=Strict`
```

Is phpinfo incorrectly reporting some variables?

Comment: Are you calling `phpinfo()` from the same script, after you've set those settings, or are you calling it before or separately? Those settings are runtime settings that will only be set during that specific request.

Comment: That is a good question. I thought the parameteres only have to be set the first time `session_start` is called and a new session is generated. Apparently PHP decides to modify the cookie settings _everytime_ `session_start` is called (!). So I made a wrapper for session_start settng the `session_set_cookiyparams` and `session_start`.

Comment: PHP doesn't "modify" your settings. It just does what it's told. Someone needs to renew their acquaintance with a *stateless* HTTP protocol.

Comment: _"That is a good question"_ - I know, but you forgot to answer. Every request in PHP starts fresh. If you override any global settings (your php.ini) at runtime (as you're doing here), those settings will _always_ just be valid during the life cycle of that specific request. The next request will start from scratch again, and you will need to override the global settings again. If that wasn't the case, you wouldn't be able to run multiple applications that needs different settings on the same server.

Comment: true. but there is only _one_ session between browser and server at one time. I now see that session parameters can change during _the same_ session and are rather fluid, which I consider not intuitive if not a potential security risk.